stuck on "still waiting for dracut initqueue hook" timeout
In an attempt to use my TPM module to automatically unlock the LUKS-encrypted LVM volume, I followed a guide and set up /etc/crypttab and installed dracut which then proceeded to create what I think are new initrd images (but it complained about a bunch of modules not existing).
When I rebooted the system, it hangs for a long time on "initializing ramdisk" and then repeatedly prints
Warning: dracut-initqueue: starting timeout scripts
Warning: dracut-initqueue: still waiting for following initqueue hooks:
Warning: /lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv.sh: (cut for brevity)

And then finally prints Warning: could not boot before dropping me into an emergency mode shell.
I'm not actually sure how to fix this. I don't know how to use the emergency shell, so I've tried using an Ubuntu live cd and unlocking the encrypted partition, chrooting into it and undoing the changes from the guide and regenerating initrd images, but to no avail.
My lack of understanding of what goes on at a boot process and which files are loaded by which process is probably what's between me and the solution. Grub is responsible for loading initrd? And it finds initrd at the /boot partition? And I can use update-initramfs to create new initrd images? And initrd tries to load whatever script it is that's stuck? Is that correct? Is there a way to remove those hooks from the initrd script?
How can I fix this?
For completeness:

It's an EFI system
Secure boot is on
Dualboot with Windows
LVM was installed with LUKS encryption on the other partition


Here are the steps I took to resolve it.

Boot with an Ubuntu Live CD, connect to a network, and run a terminal
Find out what your encrypted volume is called (mine was dm_crypt-0). If you don't know it, you may have to first open it under a different name, mount it, peek in /etc/crypttab (it's the name in the first column), unmount and rename using dmsetup rename <different-name> <actual-name>
Find out what partition the encrypted volume is on using lsblk (it's the one with reference to crypt or luks, mine was /dev/nvme0n1p6)
Open the protected volume: cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p6 dm_crypt-0
Mount it and bind system directories:

sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /mnt  # the name of my LV
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts  # unsure if the above doesn't already cover this


Chroot into the new system: sudo chroot /mnt
Mount all required partitions mount -a
If you were using systemd-resolved, your /etc/resolv.conf will be empty as systemd does not want to run in a chrooted system, so enter nameserver <ip.to.your.dns> and save it. We can now use apt.
Make sure we have the tools for enabling encrypted drives with initramfs apt install cryptsetup-initramfs
I removed everything that smelled of dracut: apt remove dracut-core dracut dracut-install and apt purge dracut*
(This was key for me) I also disabled /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades and update-notifier by entering exit 0; directly after the shebang line (because for some reason kernel installation was hanging there, leading to the image installation not completing)
The next step can probably be resolved by running update-initramfs -u -k all and update-grub2 but I had a kernel install lying around so I installed that instead dpkg -i linux-* which ran update-initramfs and update-grub2 for me.
Make sure there are no errors or warnings about missing entries from crypttab.
exit the chroot and unmount all volumes (starting with the deepest). Not sure if this is strictly required, but it's safer. I also closed the encrypted volume using cryptsetup luksClose ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv (multiple times as you have to close the parent structure as well) and finally cryptsetup luksClose dm_crypt-0.
Reboot.


This saved my Debian 12 install after installing dracut as well. I'm so happy I don't have to re-install my OS. Thanks a lot!
